# Problemas com autoload no PHP

Tags: php, php-autoload

Tenho a seguinte função de autoload de classes no meu sistema, está funcionando perfeitamente em localhost, porém quando subi para o servidor deu erro ao incluir a classe

> Erro na linha: 47 :: Não foi possivel incluir check.class.php 
>   /home/u291106554/public_html/home/_app/config.inc.php

Já pesquisei sobre o assunto, sem sucesso, também já verifiquei a versão do php que está rodando no servidor (está na 5.5).

Preciso de uma ajuda.

Código:

```
// AUTOLOAD DE CLASSES #######################
function __autoload($Class) {
$cDir = ['Conn', 'Helpers', 'Models', 'Library'];
$iDir = null;

foreach ($cDir as $dirname) {
    if (!$iDir && file_exists(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $dirname . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $Class . '.class.php') && !is_dir(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $dirname . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $Class . '.class.php')) {
        include_once (__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $dirname . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $Class . '.class.php');
        $iDir = TRUE;
    }
}

if (!$iDir) {
    trigger_error("Não foi possivel incluir {$Class}.class.php", E_USER_ERROR);
    die;
}
}
```

Comment: É linux o servidor?

Comment: Sim, estou usando hostinger(free para testar)

Comment: Então verifica o nome do arquivo e o nome classe eles devem ser iguais, lembre q o linux é case sensitive o windows não.

Comment: @rray Os nomes estão corretos, tanto do arquivo quanto da classe.

Comment: já que __autoload está como deprecated na versão mais recente do PHP (7.2), esperimenta usar `spl_autoload_register`.