# Como carregar classes com autoload em servidor web e local

Tags: php

Estou precisando fazer com que o meu arquivo que faz a instância das classes do meu projeto funcione tanto no servidor web como no servidor local.

Esse é o arquivo que faz o autoload, o autoload.php

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register ( function ($classe){ 
    $classesDiretorio = __DIR__.'/classes/';

    $classesArquivo = $classesDiretorio . ' / ' . $classe . '.php';

    if(file_exists($classesArquivo)){
        require_once ($classesArquivo)
    }   
});
```

No xampp, ele funciona direitinho, porém quando subo para o site, ele dá erro no endereço do caminho.

Segue o erro:

> Fatal error: Class 'Cliente' not found in
>   /home/diego325/public_html/temporario/rental/cadastro.php
>   on line 13

Como posso fazer com que o autoload pegue os caminhos tanto no servidor local como no servidor web?

Acredito que o meu problema é semelhante a esse:

[Problemas com autoload no PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131545/problemas-com-autoload-no-php)

Porém no problema mencionado acima não houve uma solução.

Comment: Existe um diretório chamado `classes` em `/temporario/rental/`, contendo o arquivo `Cliente.php`?

Comment: Aparentemente não há nada errado. O código que apresentou funciona bem em ambientes diversos, exceto pelo uso da constante `__DIR__` pois essa é disponível a partir do PHP5.3 http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php. Se não for esse o problema, verifique se os nomes dos arquivos estão de acordo, com letras maiúsculas e minúsculas. O sistema de arquivos do linux é case sensitive. Se o arquivo for **cliente.php**, vai dar esse erro. Deve ser **Cliente.php** (presumo).

Comment: Opa Wanderson, tem sim. É esse que uso para instanciar a classe Cliente.

Comment: Então Daniel, é esse __DIR__ mesmo que está dando o problema. No meu caso é servidor linux mesmo. A versão do php no servidor é 5.6.30. Tentei fazer uso dos valores de $_SERVER, mas não tive sucesso.

Comment: podes sempre experimentar substituir o `__DIR__` por `dirname(__FILE__)` e ver se resolve o problema. Deves também levar em consideração o `/`, que pode variar a critério do servidor, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ?

Answer (score 0):

```
DEFINE('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
DEFINE('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
DEFINE('PUBLIC_PATH', ROOT . DS . 'public');
DEFINE('PRIVATE_PATH', ROOT . DS . 'private');
DEFINE('LIB_PATH', PRIVATE_PATH . DS . 'lib');
DEFINE('CLASS_PATH', LIB_PATH . DS . 'classes');

spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    foreach(get_defined_constants(true)['user'] as $path)
    {
        if($path === DS){ continue; }
        if(file_exists($path . DS . $class . '.php')){
            require_once $path . DS . $class . '.php';
        }
    }
});
```

Fora isso, que pessoalmente não sei quão **eficiente** ou **problemático** poderá ser, ainda assim é funcional. Podes também optar pela definição através de arrays, especificando os directórios a serem verificados para o carregamento automático que acho bem mais fácil de se usar.

Answer (score 0):

Como o post é antigo, talvez vc. já tenha resolvido...
Eu uso Xampp (MacOs) e coloco sempre meus includes fora da raiz, por segurança.
Mas não uso o **DIR** e sim o $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT’] para definir o path, seja no servidor local ou remoto:

```
    define('INC_PATH',str_replace('/www','',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).’meudiretoriodeincludes/‘);
```

ou, dependendo do servidor remoto, adicione uma barra antes do diretório de includes:

```
    define('INC_PATH',str_replace('/www','',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).’/meudiretoriodeincludes/‘);
```

Resolvido o path...